# How do I validate the Continuity of Care Document that developed for PHR and EMR?

Tags: validation, ccd, hl7-v3, c-cda

How do I validate the Continuity of Care Document that developed for PHR and EMR? is there any validation tools or site available that is authorized by HL7 V3?

Comment: NIST validation is one of the standard CCDA validation tool use this link for that:
http://cda-validation.nist.gov/cda-validation/validation.html

Comment: That tool is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official validator hosted by HL7 at this time. If you've got the time and know-how, they do provide the schema and schematron that allows for testing with the C-CDA download package (requires a login to HL7.org, but free) http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=492

The US agency for health information technology (healthit.gov known as ONC) hosts a website with a bunch of online validation tools for C-CDA. That's a good place to start: 
https://sitenv.org/home

Click on C-CDA Sandbox and then click on C-CDA validator. You can upload a sample there and see if you get any errors (which you would want to address). There will likely be a lot of warnings which may be worked depending on your use case.

There's also another called the "C-CDA Scorecard" on that site as well. This isn't a validator but checks for some common errors in the semantics of C-CDA creation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [NIST Validation Tool](http://cda-validation.nist.gov/cda-validation/validation.html) as @VibinGuvera recommended.

Comment: No longer available. "UPDATE MAY 2018: The online version of the CDA Guideline Validation Tool will no longer be available after June 2018. If you still need access to validation, please download the schematron packages. Thank you."